# How to make comments appear without reloading the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I use Ruby on Rails 5.2 and Mongoid

When I add a new comment it does not appear, I have to reload the page to see it

I can't understand what is the reason why it does not work

log:

```
Started POST "/stories/alert-test-1/comments" for ::1 at 2019-07-18 12:16:22 +0300
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"text"=>"Test comment"}, "commit"=>"Post", "post_id"=>"alert-test-1"}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | remotely_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"posts", "filter"=>{"_slugs"=>{"$in"=>["alert-test-1"]}}, "limit"=>1, "sort"=>{"created_at"=>-1}, "lsid"=>{"id"=><BSON::Binary:0x70324575353440 type=uuid data=0xde9d0a99e1174026...>}}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | remotely_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.001s
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | remotely_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5d23bc2b1996da03ae5735e7')}, "sort"=>{"_id"=>1}, "limit"=>1, "singleBatch"=>true, "lsid"=>{"id"=><BSON::Binary:0x70324575353440 type=uuid data=0xde9d0a99e1174026...>}}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | remotely_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.001s
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | remotely_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5d23bc2b1996da03ae5735e7')}, "limit"=>1, "singleBatch"=>true, "lsid"=>{"id"=><BSON::Binary:0x70324575353440 type=uuid data=0xde9d0a99e1174026...>}}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | remotely_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.001s
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | remotely_development.insert | STARTED | {"insert"=>"comments", "ordered"=>true, "documents"=>[{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5d3038e61996da7af313fa4b'), "text"=>"Test comment", "commentable_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5d2c8f321996da09862539f8'), "commentable_type"=>"Post", "user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5d23...
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | remotely_development.insert | SUCCEEDED | 0.000s
  Rendering comments/create.js.erb
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | remotely_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"comments", "filter"=>{"commentable_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5d2c8f321996da09862539f8'), "commentable_type"=>"Post"}, "lsid"=>{"id"=><BSON::Binary:0x70324575353440 type=uuid data=0xde9d0a99e1174026...>}}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | remotely_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.001s
  Rendered comments/_delete_comment_form.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered comments/_single_comment.html.erb (8.6ms)
  Rendered collection of comments/_comment.html.erb [1 times] (12.9ms)
  Rendered comments/create.js.erb (21.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 83ms (Views: 61.5ms | MongoDB: 0.0ms)
```

create.js.erb

```
$(".comments").html("<%= j render @commentable.comments %>")
$("textarea").val("")
```

_comment.html.erb

```
<li id="<%= comment.id %>">
  <%= render partial: 'comments/single_comment', locals: { comment: comment } %>
</li>
```

_single_comment.html.erb

```
<span class="user"><%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %></span>
<span class="content"><%= comment.text %></span>
<div class="timestamp">
  <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago.
</div>
<% if current_user?(comment.user) %>
  <%= render partial: 'comments/delete_comment_form', locals: { comment: comment } %>
<% end %>
```

comments/show.html.erb

```
<div class="comments">
<%= render partial: 'comments/single_comment', locals: { comment: @comment } %>
</div>
```

posts/show.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/comment_form', locals: { commentable: @post } %>
<%= render @post.comments %>
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, I formatted

Comment: Indeed, log looks ok. Are there any errors in browser console? And show how you render the comments on server-side (in that `post.html.erb` view or whatever it is)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  no errors in console

Comment: Is that the entirety of `posts/show.html.erb`? If so, no wonder that comments don't appear on the page. There's no `.comments` element

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That's all. What I need to add I can't understand?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you very much I understood, it was necessary to add div class: `<div class="comments">
  <%= render @post.comments %>
</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
$(".comments").html("<%= j render @commentable.comments %>")
```

requires that there's at least one element on the page, which matches CSS selector `.comments`. If there's no such element, this line has no effect.